# Django:How to pass a foreign key value in pre_save signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This are my models:

```
class Ledger1(models.Model):
    creation_Date   = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,blank=True, null=True)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    group1_Name     = models.ForeignKey(Group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='ledgergroups')

class Journal(models.Model):
    date            = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    voucher_id      = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    voucher_type    = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    by              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    to              = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    debit           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    credit          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True)
```

This is my signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Journal)
def pl_journal(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.Debit != None or instance.Credit != None or instance.By.group1_Name.group_Name == 'Indirect Expense':
        Journal.objects.update_or_create(date=instance.date, voucher_id=instance.id, voucher_type= "Journal",by=instance.by,to=Ledger1.objects.get(name='Profit & Loss A/c'),debit=instance.debit,credit=instance.credit)
```

I want to pass a `pre_save` signal that whenever a `Journal` objects is created which is having a `Group1` object name of `Indirect Expense` another journal with the same `by`  with the `to` value of   `'Profit & Loss A/c'` should be automatically created...

This line of code is giving me a error:

```
Ledger1.objects.get(name='Profit & Loss A/c')
```

Error:

```
get() returned more than one Ledger1 -- it returned 2!
```

Can anyone tell me how to get a Foreign key object in a pre_save signal?

Thank you

Comment: get() will return one instance, but the query u pass return 2 results which causes the exception above, u should use some unique values in get().

Comment: Do I need to filter something?

Comment: I want to pass the object name `Profit & Loss A/c` of `ledger1` model in `to` feild of Journal model...Is there another way of doing it rather than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get() is to be used when you expect only one result to be returned. 
So, you should use some other unique input which returns the only unique result you would expect.

Alternatively, if you actually want more than 1 result to be returned, use the filter() method instead. Something like,

```
Ledger1.objects.filter(name='Profit & Loss A/c')
```

But in your case, it seems only 1 result is expected, so I recommend using a unique input or a workaround would be :-

```
Ledger1.objects.filter(name='Profit & Loss A/c').first()
```

This would return a single result which is only the first fetched result, if that's okay with the kind of logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: This will give me this error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`...I want to get only the name `Profit & Loss A/c` from ledger1 object.